# jQuery tablesorter - hyphen along with numbers with decimals (floats) causing sorting issues

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

**Requirement**
My table can have values like these -

```
1.00
0.00
23.10
-
35.00
-
22.00
0.00
0.00
```

I would it to be sorted like this (all hyphens should be in the end) -

```
1.00
22.00
23.10
35.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
-
-
```

Or even this will be fine (all hyphens in the beginning, at least they are separate from the others) -

```
-
-
0.00
0.00
0.00
1.00
22.00
23.10
35.00
```

**What I did**
I am using a custom sorter like this (this is the one we use in our project and it is working perfectly fine for integers and decimal numbers, i.e. float types) -

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
        // set a unique id
        id: 'formattedNumbers',
        is: function(s){
            // return false so this parser is not auto detected
            return false;
        },
        format: function(s){
        // format your data for normalization
            return s.replace(/,/g, '').replace(/%/g, ''); //removes comma separator from formatted numbers

        },
        // set type, either numeric or text
        type: 'numeric'
    });
```

And calling it like this -

```
$("#"+report_type).tablesorter({
                    indexing: true,
                    textExtraction: 'complex',
                    headers : 1: {
                                        { sorter: 'formattedNumbers' },
                                    },
                    widgets :['zebra'],
                    sortList:[[0,0]]
                });
```

**Result I am getting**
But I am getting unpredictable results. The numbers other than 0.00 and hyphen (-) get sorted correctly among themselves, but some of the 0.00 and hyphen remain scattered randomly. Like this -

```
0.00
1.00
22.00
0.00
-
23.10
-
35.00
0.00
-
```

**My thoughts**

We need to change the logic inside the custom sorter so as to handle the hyphen character. I tried looking for Natural sorting as suggested in [jQuery tablesorter - sorting a column with mixed text and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157926/jquery-tablesorter-sorting-a-column-with-mixed-text-and-numbers) but did not find any working custom sorter like our "formattedNumbers".

Comment: Dude, you can try one thing here, for - value you can use -== -1, this may solve your problem,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friend, do change in your add parser code.

Old code

```
format: function(s){
            // format your data for normalization
                return s.replace(/,/g, '').replace(/%/g, ''); //removes comma separator from formatted numbers

            }
```

After the suggestions given by Mottie.

Updated code

```
format: function(s){
            // format your data for normalization
                s = s.replace(/,/g, '').replace(/%/g, ''); //removes comma, percentage 
                if(s && s.trim() && s.trim().length==1){
                       s = s.replace(/-/g,'');                  
                   }
                return s;
    }
```

Hope, this will solve your problem.
In the scenario given by you(values contains more zeros and there is no negative number appearing), to make it look more beautiful you can replace '-' with -1 to separate it from zeros.

Updated version (if you are sure there will be no data<0):

```
format: function(s){
            // format your data for normalization
                s = s.replace(/,/g, '').replace(/%/g, ''); //removes comma, percentage 
                if(s && s.trim() && s.trim().length==1){
                       s = s.replace(/-/g,'-1');                  
                   }
                return s;
    }
```

Cheers.

Comment: I won't downvote you, because I think this is a good learning point, but replacing the dash will corrupt the data if the column includes negative numbers (e.g. `-5.00`).

Comment: @Mottie thanks for your quick observation and pointing out my mistake.

Comment: @lokeshjain2008 Thanks! your solution fixes the sorting issue to one level, i.e. the zeroes and hyphens now only appear in the lower end of the sorted result, but in a bunch withing the limit of which, they are scattered). This is one sample sorted result after applying your solution - `0.00 - 0.00 0.00 - - 1.00 22.00 23.10 35.00` (You can see that the 0.00s and hyphens appear in a bunch in the beginning, where they are not sorted, but after that, i.e. after the 1.00, no zero or hyphen appears).

Comment: Considering your comment above, where you mention replacing hyphens with -1, since this fits my requirement, I replaced the `s = s.replace(/-/g,'');` in your answer with `s = s.replace(/-/g,-1);` and now I have even the zeroes and hyphens sorted, inside their bunch.

Comment: @SandeepanNath, I am glad you found your solution. Have a good day.

Comment: @lokeshjain2008 - u can consider updating ur answer with the logic of updating hyphens with -1. I can accept this answer since it best matches my current scenario, without doing much changes.

Answer (score 1):

The default sorter method of tablesorter will give you

```
0.00
0.00
0.00
1.00
22.00
23.10
35.00
-
-
```

Or

```
-
-
35.00
23.10
22.00
1.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
```

take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6eMv/2/

I don't understand the goal of having that result :

```
1.00
22.00
23.10
35.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
-
-
```

Could give more detail of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Since no HTML was shared, we can only assume that the hypens in the markup don't include extra spaces, tabs or other invisible characters. The tablesorter parser is set as "numeric" but a string is being returned, so the comparison may not be correct.

As @Xiaodoudou showed in the jsFiddle example, my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) will sort the hypens properly.

In addition, you can make non-numerical data (strings) sort at the bottom of the column - see [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers-digits-strings.html). No extra parser is needed and all you would need to do is add a `sort-bottom` class to the column's `<th>` - try out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/1354/).

```
<th class="string-bottom">Numeric</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do array and use sort method:

```
tab.sort(function(a,b){ 
    if(b==0){
      return -1
    }
    else if(a==0){
      return 1
    }
    else{
      return (a-b)
    }
})
```